# Is it possible to reverse lookup the index position for itersorted in PyTables?

Tags: python, pytables

**Context**

Multi GB database with a simple table that has a column with a completely sorted index (CSI).
To iterate through the index **without loading all the rows in a batch** like `where` we can:

```
for row in itersorted('indexed_column', step=1):
    print row
```

This works fine, the next step can be to iterate from a certain index position like:

```
for row in itersorted('indexed_column', start=position, step=1):
    print row
```

Now the **caveat**: that position is the position in the index and not the row number! And it is very easy to find row numbers (`Row.nrow`) with `where`, `get_where_list`, etc.

**Problem**

Is it possible to do a fast reverse lookup of the index position of a certain value of the indexed column for [itersorted(start=position)](http://pytables.github.io/usersguide/libref/structured_storage.html?highlight=table.itersorted#tables.Table.itersorted) to be useful?

**Attempts**

- `table.cols.indexed_column.index` finds the index class but was a dead end.
- Alternatively, as said, is to do several queries using the index with `where` queries. But since I am simulating a stream and [itersorted(start=position)](http://pytables.github.io/usersguide/libref/structured_storage.html?highlight=table.itersorted#tables.Table.itersorted) exists I was hoping there was a more elegant way.

Comment: I don't understand, what is wrong with `itersorted(start=position)`?

Comment: I don't know how to find an index position based on a condition. I created sorted index for a column, now imagine that I want to iterate from a row with a certain value on that index. How to do that?

Comment: would also recommend what njkz2 said, or do you mean how to extract only the data having a given index? In which case you could use the read_where method

Comment: you probably want to look at `Table.where` and similar methods, then.

Comment: Table.where loads every row in a batch, which is a pain in my case.

Comment: `This method returns a Row iterator` isn't that what you want?

Comment: hm...that's a tough one. My first reflex here would be a brute-force one: Read small chunks into memory using read_where('(min<value)&(value<max)') which should be fast be cause of the index. Then sort chunk in memory and then iterate over chunks (min,max)... Not very elegant but should be possible. Alternative: dig into how the index works internally...

Comment: @njzk2: Table.where does not return sorted columns if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @user1901493 : no, but `read_where` and `get_where_list` apparently do

Comment: That seems random...bug?

Comment: where() is definitely what yo want.  It *will* use sorted indexes if possible. You can tests this with `Table.will_query_use_indexing()`  1. http://pytables.github.io/usersguide/libref/structured_storage.html?highlight=where#tables.Table.where

Comment: @Anthony Scopatz: Yes it will use the index, but will the results that you iterate over afterwards be in sorted order or the normal table row order. That is the question here, I guess.