# pytables: order of rows retrieved from a table with .where(condition)

Tags: python, performance, pytables

I am building a very large table (~10e9 rows) with PyTables. Two of the tables columns (say `idx1` and `idx2`) are indices. The first index is fully sorted. Moreover, when creating the table, I am inserting the entries in order sorted by idx1. I want to use the `.where` query for selecting my data, to make full use of the indexing.

My question is: when I iterate through the rows with the .where iterator, is there a way to guarantee the output to be sorted by the idx1 column value? Alternatively, can I assume that the iterator will return the rows in the order they were entered in? This is the case so far for me, but I didn't want to just presume.

I tried looking in the documentation, but I couldn't find anything on this topic. I know there is an `itersorted` method, but that does not allow me to fully use the indexing; I would have to emulate it myself somehow.

Many thanks in advance for all suggestions

Comment: this question seems to be very closely related to what we are discussing [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22202841/is-it-possible-to-reverse-lookup-the-index-position-for-itersorted-in-pytables)

Comment: Thanks for this. It seems that the behaviour is not well-defined. In case anyone is interested (and finds this via google...) I will just index the array myself - I know it is sorted from the start. So I just need an index that tells me where to start my searches, and iterate over the rows. That, I guess, should be sorted (or so I hope).

Comment: I guess that if the table is sorted the iterated results should be sorted too. If your data is too big to sort upfront, you can always index the first column and then copy the table using the sortby option to get a sorted copy of the table