# Why does PyTables not return the first row when using itersorted with a negative step?

Tags: python, pytables

I'm using the itersorted method in PyTables. All rows are returned correctly when the step is set to a positive value, but the first row is not returned when using a negative step value. How can I get the complete set of rows when using a negative step value?

Here is some test code that shows the problem:

```
import tables


class DBEntry(tables.IsDescription):
    id = tables.Int16Col()


class Test(object):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        pass

    def create_db_entries(self):
        db = tables.open_file("py_db_test.h5", mode = "w", title = "db")
        table = db.create_table('/', 'test', DBEntry, "test")
        entry = table.row
        for i in range(0, 5):
            entry['id'] = i
            entry.append()

        table.flush()
        table.cols.id.create_csindex()
        db.close()

    def get_db_entries(self):
        db = tables.open_file("py_db_test.h5", mode = "r")
        entries = db.root.test
        print('ascending (all rows showing)')
        for row in entries.itersorted('id', start = None, stop = None, step = 1):
            print(row['id'])
        print('decending (missing first row)')
        for row in entries.itersorted('id', start = None, stop = None, step = -1):
            print(row['id'])
        db.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = Test()
    test.create_db_entries()
    test.get_db_entries()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting problem. I added a `def` to your code to test behavior of `table.read_sorted()` with `step=-1`. That works as expected (you get the array sorted in descending order: `[(4,) (3,) (2,) (1,) (0,)]`.
Note that `start= and stop=` are positions in the index, and not the row number. See this SO Q&A for a discussion:
  [Is it possible to reverse lookup the index position for itersorted in PyTables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22202841)

I can't explain why the first row is missing with `itersorted('id', step = -1)` Maybe it's a bug?

If you really need all elements in descending order, you can use the index values as your row iterator. Add this code to your `def get_db_entries(self):`

```
print('decending (using csi index to order)')
print (entries.cols.id.index.read_indices(step = -1))
for id in entries.cols.id.index.read_indices(step = -1):
    print(entries[id][0])
```

Comment: Thanks for the great hint. I'm not sure that I should mark this as the "correct" answer, yet. Let's see if we get some more comments and answers from others.

Comment: I suspect you will need someone familiar with the Pytables code to investigate this error (especially since the `table.read_sorted()` method works). I searched the pytables-users Google Group and didn't find anything. You could also check the Pytables project on github.

Comment: I've already posted an issue in the Github project. I'll report back if I hear anything. For now, I've hacked the intersorted.py code of PyTables to set the end index to -2 (instead of -1) when using a step of -1 and this seems to fix the bug. So, perhaps it's just a "one-off" error. I'm surprised though. This would be a major bug.

Comment: I'm impressed. Did you look at the code for `table.read_sorted` method? It might be helpful to see how step=-1 is handled properly in that function. I suspect your scenario isn't done that often: reading a sorted column from bottom to top.

Comment: Good idea. I'll do that. If I find anything interesting, I'll report back here.